# Converting Ratios

Tags: probability, ratio

In a community of M men and W women, m men and w women smoke (m ≤ M,w ≤ W). If a person is selected at random and A and B are the events that the person is a man and smokes, respectively, under what conditions are A and B independent?

I have seen the question posted here before [Conditional probability. under which conditions $E$ and $F$ are independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747853/conditional-probability-under-which-conditions-e-and-f-are-independent)

Nonetheless the answer in my textbook states something more:

$$\frac{m}{M+W}=\frac{M}{M+W}\frac{m+w}{M+W}\tag{1}$$

Which implies $$\frac{m}{M}=\frac{w}{W}\tag{2}$$I do not see how this follows from the 1st equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the first equation
$$
\frac{m}{M+W} = \frac{M}{M+W} \frac{m+w}{M+W}
$$
we can multiply both sides by $\frac{M+W}{M}$ to get
$$
\frac{m}{M} = \frac{m+w}{M+W}
$$
or
$$
(M+W)m = (m+w)M \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad Mm + Wm = Mm + Mw
$$
When you cancel the term $Mm$, you get
$$
Wm = Mw
$$
which you can divide by $WM$ to get
$$
\frac{m}{M} = \frac{w}{W}
$$